# Should I insulate an attic that's over an open porch?

Tags: insulation

I have a 6ft (approx. 2m) wide porch at the front of my house.  The space above the porch opens into the attic, like this:

[Diagram of porch/attic/house goes here http://img825.imageshack.us/img825/7585/diyquestion.png](http://img825.imageshack.us/img825/7585/diyquestion.png)

I'm adding insulation -- R-38 fiberglass batting -- in the attic; do I need to insulate the space above the porch too?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is the porch heated?  If not, then don't bother.

The purpose of insulation is not to keep the attic warm, but to keep the house warm (or cool).  You actually want the attic to stay relatively close to the outside temperature to prevent ice problems in the winter or overheating in the summer.

Answer (score 1):

If you live in the attic, then yes!
Insulation is intended to either keep our comfort zone warm or cool, depending on the place and time of year.
If you are going to install insulation, use a closed cell insulation like Styrofoam, this is wind proof and waterproof, it can also be cut to a tight fit and in real life is the best insulation you can buy on a cost results basis.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I don't live in the attic, and I already have fiberglass batts for the rest of the space.